# Can't call node api in aws ubuntu(nginx config wrong)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I deploy the react and node server to aws ubuntu instance and install nginx for proxy passing.
React server working well and I set `location/api` for node api.

```
location /api/ {
      #rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
}
```

When I call https://www.nsfcareer.io/api then express page shows but https://www.nsfcareer.io/api/login not working.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break; in nginx config.
Then I call domain/api in frontend for calling api in backend.